# scale and draw an ico in c++ using win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I am having a 48* 48 icon file which I need to draw in 18*18 container. I am using DrawIconEx API.

```
::DrawIconEx(hdc, x, y, hicon, w, h, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);
```

Using above API draws icon in distorted form. Do I need to scale icon to 18*18 before drawing it or is there some better api to draw an icon.

Comment: I don't know how well it'd work, but you can try `StretchBlt`.

Comment: DrawIconEx() should scale your 48x48 icon to the size specified in w/h.   If w/h are either 0, it will do no scaling and will use the actual size of the resource.    Verify w/h are 18x18, and maybe include a screenshot of what behavior you are seeing.   I use DrawIconEx for scaling all the time.

Comment: @anand Have you, please, discovered the problem ?